# Two layout with same height in percentage

Tags: android, android-layout, height

I search and try a lot of things, but can not resolve my problem.
I try to make the height of two Layout be the same. Above and bottom of them, I have also Layouts but with a fixed Height. I tried a lot of solutions with height, weight...but I never have what I need.
So I want the two ViewPager have the same size and their size fill the remaining space at the center...

Is it possible ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="23dp"
        android:background="@color/taupe"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnClose"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_red_light" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/taupe">

        <TableRow android:layout_height="28dp">
            ...
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/vp_c"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="@color/background">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/vpI"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:background="@color/taupe"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnP"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btnN"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:text="@string/previous" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnN"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:text="@string/next" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:background="@color/taupe2"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/taupe2"
            app:fabSize="mini" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **weight** property to indicate that the height of your two elements is adjusted proportionally. If you want both to have the same proportion, simply set their **height to 0dp** and indicate the **same value in weight**. Something like that:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/vp_c"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@color/background">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/vpI"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Bearing this in mind, if, for example, you wanted the second element to occupy twice as much space as the first element, you would only have to indicate it that way `android:layout_weight="2"`.

Good luck!